# Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 time. this typically indicates that your device does not have healthy Internet

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am connecting javascript & firebase but got this issue,
I am facing this issue I switched networks as well but it doesn't work,
firebase v9
javascript
package file: webpack, webpack-cli

filename: index.js

```
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    import {getFirestore, collection, getDocs} from 'firebase/firestore';
    
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: ...,
        authDomain: ...,
        projectId: ...,
        storageBucket: ...,
        messagingSenderId: ...,
        appId: ...
      };
    
    // initialize application
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig, {
        experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
        useFetchStreams: false
    });

// initialize serivice
const db = getFirestore();

// collection ref
const colRef = collection(db, 'books');

// get collection data
getDocs(colRef)
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.docs)
  })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the firestore applications you need to check that your internet connection is very well,
I encounter that the internet I was working on was not well enough, I changed the connection again and restart the system,
It resolved the issue!